# Mostrar conteúdo de um JSON usando PHP e separar os campos

Tags: php, json

Tenho a URL de uma API que gera um JSON. Tenho esse código abaixo, entretanto necessito dos campos separados para eu poder criar while dos itens e separar tipo `echo $row['nome_marca']` e etc. Alguma luz?

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$jsonData = file_get_contents("http://www.folhacar.com.br/frontendnovo.php/api/listMarcas");
echo $jsonData;
?>
```

Comment: Pelo que entendo você quer decodificar o JSON. Você precisa disso no PHP mesmo, ou seria na outra ponta, no JavaScript?

Comment: já tentou usar a função json_decode do php? Isto daria para você um array - http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: Não tentei ainda pois nao tenho muita intimidade com php, mas preciso resolver isso. Poderia me fornecer um exemplo de como eu posso usar individualmente esse array posteriormente a implementação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ler os dados de um JSON você pode utilizar a função json_decode. Veja:

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.folhacar.com.br/frontendnovo.php/api/listMarcas"));
    for($i = 0; $i < count($json); $i++) {
        echo "<div>ID: " . $json[$i]->{'marca_id'} . "</div>";
        echo "<div>Marca: " . $json[$i]->{'nome_marca'} . "</div>";
        echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

A função json_decode vai retornar uma array. Em seguida, é só usar o for() para percorrê-la e ir tratando os dados.

Comment: Otimo Jhonas, exatamente o que eu precuro fazer. Muito obrigado pela atenção!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a função json_decode do PHP para transformar sua string json em algo mais legível no PHP.

Neste seu output (json) seria um array

http://php.net/json_decode

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$jsonData = file_get_contents("http://www.folhacar.com.br/frontendnovo.php/api/listMarcas");
$arrData = json_decode($jsonData); // Transforma o seu JSON
// print_r($arrData);

foreach ($arrData as $indiceDoArray => $valorDoArray) {
    echo "Elemento na posição {$indiceDoArray} tem valor {$valorDoArray}<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Perfeito, mas é aqui q eu travo: 
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/proveiculos/teste.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
Array

Como eu uso esse array? tipo "echo $row[campo'];